# My h2 database is not found in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

I am working on the Spring Boot app and want to use the in-memory h2-database for testing purposes on my machine. The configuration has to be done in a yml file. The application uses Hibernate as JPA implementation - I created a few entity classes marked with @Entity annotation, so I would also expect to see the table after eventually accessing the database.

Unfortunately, I cannot access my h2-database and getting an error: Database "mem:/mydatabase" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-200] 90149/90149"

I have been trying various ways of fixing the problem like different db types (eg. file) or adding/removing items from the application.yml file. Unluckily, none of them worked.

I don't have a clue whether I am missing something or what. All hints will be very much appreciated.

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8081

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:/mydatabase
    username: sa
    password:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2
      settings:
        web-allow-others: true
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

Entity example

```
import lombok.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Accident {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "machine")
    private long machine;

    @Column(name = "accidenttype")
    private int accidentType;

    @Column(name="startedat")
    private LocalDateTime startedAt;

    @Column(name = "reportedat")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime reportedAt;

}
```

[image: h2 condole]

[image: App logs saying that h2 database is available]

Comment: What is the error log?

Comment: Try to remove "/" in your database address, like `jdbc:h2:mem:mydatabase`.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri thank you for your hint - it actually does work without '/' (I thought I tried this way and it did not work...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@maciejd The problem is with the database availability. I can see your log statement showing the database url with a random identifier.
It should be like this in the logs and then you can only access it.

H2 console available at '/h2'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:mydatabase'

The only change you need to make in the yml file is to change /mydatabase to mydatabase

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydatabase
    username: sa
    password:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
```

[image]

Comment: yeah it works! I don't know why, but I thought I tried this way and it didn't work... Nevertheless, the issue has been solved and I'm very grateful for your hint. Thanks!